# Zapier variable propagation

Tags: zapier

I'm looking for a way of propagating information between the authentication script I've setup in my Zapier app and the different actions/triggers I have. The data I am receiving is from authentication API which I want to use further in Triggers and Actions. I guess the environment global var is not the way as it's not bound to a specific zap but for all usages of the app. Thank you for your help!

Tried setting value in bundle.authData in code mode while authenticating user, but it's reflecting across triggers and actions.

Comment: What type of auth are you using?

Comment: API Key authentication, but Session authentication solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

API Key authentication does not support the ability to save off keys you might need later, only Session and OAUTH provide this ability. This are computed field and docs about it are here:

https://platform.zapier.com/docs/session#computed-fields